# onClick of button triggering all the components to open - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I implemented a Card component and basically generating a bunch of cards on some input data. I binded a setter function on button click on every card which basically expands and collapse it. Even after putting unique keys to the div is sort of triggering all the cards to open at once.

Here is the code piece:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import PrettyPrintJson from './PrettyPrintJson';
import './Card.scss';
import '../App.scss';

const Card = (props) => {
    const { data } = props;
    const [collapse, toggleCollapse] = useState(true);

    return (<div className="card-group">
    {data.map((obj, idx)=>{
        return <div className="card" key={`${idx}_${obj?.lastModifiedOn}`}>
        <div className="card-header">
            <h4 className="card-title">{`fId: ${obj?.fId}`}</h4>
            <h6 className="card-title">{`name: ${obj?.name}`}</h6>
            <h6 className="card-title">{`status: ${obj?.status}`}</h6>
            <div className="heading-elements">
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => toggleCollapse(!collapse)}>Show Json</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className={`card-content ${!collapse ? 'collapse show' : 'collapsing'}`}>
            <div className="card-body">
                <div className="row">
                <PrettyPrintJson data={ obj } />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    })}
    </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: All cards are opening because you are using the same state to do it. Try creating a different state for every card.

Comment: There are more than 50 cards I guess, Do I have to create fifty states manually? :/ @Ariel

Comment: No, you don't have to do that. Instead, how about from the map you return a separate component (which will render the card - i.e., the div having the className `card`), and then that component should have a `collapse` state variable?

Comment: Create a state with the I'd of the open card and make tha the condition in your class name prop

Comment: @Jazz I tried it, but sort of only allowing one card to open, basically i want to expand more than one card and collapse the same

Comment: create a component that manages it's own state

Comment: Any example or reference @JuniusL.

Comment: In that case Junius suggestion is best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a component that manages it's own state and render that component.

```
const CardItem = ({ obj }) => {

  const [collapse, toggleCollapse] = useState(true);

  return (<div className="card">
  <div className="card-header">
      <h4 className="card-title">{`fId: ${obj?.fId}`}</h4>
      <h6 className="card-title">{`name: ${obj?.name}`}</h6>
      <h6 className="card-title">{`status: ${obj?.status}`}</h6>
      <div className="heading-elements">
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => toggleCollapse(!collapse)}>Show Json</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div className={`card-content ${!collapse ? 'collapse show' : 'collapsing'}`}>
      <div className="card-body">
          <div className="row">
          <PrettyPrintJson data={ obj } />
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>)
}
```

then render it like

```
{data.map((obj, idx)=> (<CardItem obj={obj} key={idx} />))}
```

Comment: It worked. But I wonder even after putting a map why it's sort of combining all the cards to the same state. I feel like this approach sort of prepare an isolated context resulting a seperate state for every card. Thought? @Junius L.

Comment: you want to close the opened card and open the new one?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can declare a state which is a type of int. After then, you can use the if-statement of index(idx) and state.

Like this:

```js
const [collapsedCardNumbers, toggleCollapseCard] = useState([]);
const addCardNumber = (idx, prevState) => {
const arr_cardNum = prevState
!arr_cardNum .includes(idx) && arr_cardNum .push(idx)
return arr_cardNum
}

    ...

        {data.map((obj, idx)=>{
                return <div className="card" key={`${idx}_${obj?.lastModifiedOn}`}>
                <div className="card-header">
                    <h4 className="card-title">{`fId: ${obj?.fId}`}</h4>
                    <h6 className="card-title">{`name: ${obj?.name}`}</h6>
                    <h6 className="card-title">{`status: ${obj?.status}`}</h6>
                    <div className="heading-elements">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => toggleCollapseCard(prevState => addCardNumber(idx, prevState))}>Show Json</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={`card-content ${collapsedCardNumbers.includes(idx) ? 'collapse show' : 'collapsing'}`}>
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <div className="row">
                        <PrettyPrintJson data={ obj } />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            })}
```

Comment: Once you click on another card, It'll sort close the opened one. @camper

Comment: then plz declare a state which is a type of array. I will update code soon

Comment: you're mutating state ```prevState.push(idx))```

Comment: Oh sorry. I was just confused :(